# "The address you have provided cannot be validated" Error in Twilio address create

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I've tried to create new addresses in my Twilio sub-account, but it gave this error response "**The address you provided cannot be validated**".

**This address country is United Kingdom**.

How to add this address?[image: error response]

Answer (score 0):

I had to put a space in the state box, I am in the UK. Until I did that it wouldn't let me proceed.

I also had to use https://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode to match up the address. Only then did it start working.